# How do I make my nextLine() wait for the user's input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
        System.out.print("Player " + i + ", Please Enter your name : ");
        String PlayerName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 0 and 9 : ");
        int PlayerNumber = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(PlayerName + " : " + PlayerNumber);
    }
```

Output : `Player 1, Please Enter your name : Please enter a number between 0 and 9 :`

If I change `input.nextLine` to `input.next` , it will wait for the users first input but he/she won't be able to write their full name.

My question : What can I change so the user can input his full name first and then his number?

Comment: s it possible to do this from points list: new LatLng(points.get(i).latitude, points.get(i).lontitude)?

Comment: By the way, please don't capitalize  your variable names

Comment: I tried the "duplicate question" method but it still doesn't work. If I put a `input.nextLine();` below my `String PlayerName = input.nextLine();` , my output becomes `[blank] : PlayerNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consume the *newLine* after `input.nextInt()`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
    input.nextLine(); //add this to top
    System.out.print("Player " + i + ", Please Enter your name : ");
    String PlayerName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 0 and 9 : ");
    int PlayerNumber = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println(PlayerName + " : " + PlayerNumber);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same output, but if I move the `input.nextLine` below the `String PlayerName = input.nextLine();` , the output will be `[blank] : PlayerNumber`

Comment: @Crypto check the updated code. Also,are you calling `nextInt` before the for loop ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to Java. I'm still getting the same output with your code. 

Output : 
`Player 1, Please Enter your name : Please enter a number between 0 and 9 :`

Comment: @Crypto try now, I guess your problem should be fixed now.

Comment: Wow it works! Can you please explain why adding `input.nextLine();` doesn't make the scanner skip to the other one? I can't seem to understand other topics on this

Comment: @Crypto Glad to help! I suppose you called `nextInt` before the for loop, which caused the problem. Check out the duplicate question for the Explanation. It just consumes the extra newline, which `nextInt` doesn't

Comment: I kind of understand the concept now. Thank you again for the help man. Now I just have to figure out how to how to add the inputs to an list of some kind so I can fetch them and compare them to the winning number.